# How make accessible a SonarQube server installed in Centos Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, centos, sonarqube

I have an EC2 instance in which I have installed as OS a Linux CentOS.
I need to have a sonarQube up and running on it and accessible from the IP attached to that EC2 instance:

tools installed:
- Java
- Mysql
- SonarQube 6.2

When I go to the internet, outside the EC2 machine, and I type the url of that EC2 instance, nothing comes up.

I did make sure that SonarQube and Mysql are both up and running as services.

Could you guys suggest me something to do in here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your EC2 instance needs to be an a subnet with a routing table that contains a routing entry for all but the local traffic ( `0.0.0.0/0` ) to a IGW (internet gateway) you created and attached to your VPC.

[image: My routing table]

Also, the SG (Security Group) attached to your EC2 instance should have a rule to allow incoming HTTP(S) traffic, and your subnet ACL should also allow incoming and outgoing (ACL is stateless) HTTP(S) traffic.